# callback to clean pointers (MCVE : auto eject traitor Soldier from Vehicle)

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++14

In my game, `Soldier` that becomes a traitor will be automatically *ejected* from `Turret`, `Tank`, and a lot of holder.   ([MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/305857c95d6d1900))

A `Soldier` can reside in 1 `Turret` and 1 `Tank` at the same time.
A `Soldier` can reside in at most 1 `Turret` and at most 1 `Tank`.

Here is the `Soldier`, `Turret` and `Tank` class (In real cases, they are in 3 files) :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct Soldier{
    private: int team=0;
    public: void setTeam(int teamP){
        team=teamP;
        //should insert callback
    }
};
struct Turret{
    Soldier* gunner=nullptr;
    //currently it is so easy to access Turret's gunner
};
struct Tank {
    std::vector<Soldier*> passenger;
    //currently it is so easy to access Tank's passenger by index
};
std::vector<Soldier*> global_soldier;
std::vector<Turret*> global_turret;
std::vector<Tank*> global_tank;
```

Here is the `main()`.
Currently whenever programmer want to set team of any instance of `Soldier`, he has to do the *ejection* manually :-

```
int main(){
    Soldier soldier1; global_soldier.push_back(&soldier1);
    Turret turret1;   global_turret.push_back(&turret1);
    turret1.gunner=&soldier1;
    //v game loop
    soldier1.setTeam(2);
    //v manual ejection (should be callback?)
    for(auto& ele: global_turret){  
        if(ele->gunner==&soldier1){
            ele->gunner=nullptr;
        }
    }
    for(auto& ele: global_tank){
        for(auto& elePass: ele->passenger){
            if(elePass==&soldier1){
                elePass=nullptr;
            }
        }
    }
    //^ manual ejection
    std::cout<<"should print 1="<<(turret1.gunner==nullptr)<<std::endl;
}
```

This leads to a lot of boilerplate code after every call of `Soldier::setTeam(int)` (maintenance problem) and performance problem.

How to fix it?

**Current advantage that I don't want to lose :**-
- It is so easy to access the Turret's gunner, and one of a Tank's passenger by index.

### My workaround ([MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0ec1a134daae83e))

In `Soldier`, I created a callback hub (`callback_changeTeams`).
In `Turret` and `Tank`, I create a callback definition to `Soldier` (`Turret::ChangeTeam` and `Tank::ChangeTeam`).

Here is the working code.
`Soldier` :-

```
class Soldier;
struct Callback{
    public: virtual void changeTeam_virtual(Soldier* soldier)=0;
};
std::vector<Callback*> callback_changeTeams;
struct Soldier{
    private: int team=0;
    public: void setTeam(int teamP){
        if(team==teamP){

        }else{
            team=teamP;
            for(auto callback :callback_changeTeams) 
                callback->changeTeam_virtual(this);
        }
        //should insert callback
    }
};
```

`Turret` :-

```
struct Turret;
std::vector<Turret*> global_turret;
struct Turret{
    Soldier* gunner=nullptr;
    struct ChangeTeam : public Callback{
        public: virtual void changeTeam_virtual(Soldier* soldier){
            for(auto& ele: global_turret){  
                if(ele->gunner==soldier){
                    ele->gunner=nullptr;
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
```

`Tank` (similar as Turret's ) :-

```
struct Tank;
std::vector<Tank*> global_tank;
struct Tank {
    std::vector<Soldier*> passenger;
    struct ChangeTeam : public Callback{
        public: virtual void changeTeam_virtual(Soldier* soldier){
            for(auto& ele: global_tank){
                for(auto& elePass: ele->passenger){
                    if(elePass==soldier){
                        elePass=nullptr;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Main :-

```
std::vector<Soldier*> global_soldier;
int main(){
    Turret::ChangeTeam turretCallback;
    Tank::ChangeTeam tankCallback;
    callback_changeTeams.push_back(&turretCallback);
    callback_changeTeams.push_back(&tankCallback);
    Soldier soldier1; global_soldier.push_back(&soldier1);
    Turret turret1;   global_turret.push_back(&turret1);
    turret1.gunner=&soldier1;
    //v game loop
    soldier1.setTeam(2);
    //v should be callback

    std::cout<<"should print 1="<<(turret1.gunner==nullptr)<<std::endl;
}
```

**Disadvantages:-**

**1. Duplication code between `Turret` & `Tank`.**
Not so bad, but in real case, I have a lot of `Turret`-like (that store a pointer to `Soldier`) and `Tank`-like (that store array of `Soldier`).   It would be a lot of code duplication.

**2. Still Bad performance.** 
I have to iterate every `Turret` and `Tank` whenever I just change a team setting of a `Soldier`.
This can be solved by cache parent `Turret` and `Tank`, so iteration is not required.
However, in real case, I have a lot of parent type and it would be dirty e.g. :-

```
struct Soldier{
    //... some field / functions ...
    Turret* parentTurret;
    Tank* parentTank;
    SomeParentClass1* parent1;
    SomeParentClass2* parent2;   // bra bra bra.. ... dirty messy
};
```

---

**My random ideas** (not much useful) :  Smart pointer (`std::shared_ptr`);  `std::unordered_map` ; change design-pattern; make the callbacks commit as batch; I am using Entity Component System.

Comment: Did you consider making a base class `holder` inherited by `tank` and `turret` and maintaining a global list of all holders to iterate for ejection?

Comment: Did you consider referencing from each turret the tank it is attached to and from each soldier the turret or tank it is inside? This would also use the base class mentioned above. That way you'd only have to eject the soldier from whatever it is directly in. Being kicked from the turret would also see you out of the tank. Of course there is a different way of leaving the turret, which has you end up in the tank.

Comment: @Yunnosch  2 Question : 1) Yes, it is OK.  2) No, it is not applicable with current design. ...  In your approach : If a soldier is commanded eject from a tank, I have to update the list as well `O(parent)` or the slow `std::unordered_set<ParentBase*>`.   Hmm, it might be not much slow.  Thanks.

Comment: @Yunnosch Another downside of the approach : every time a soldier enter/eject, from the code `turretPtr->gunner=soldierPtr;`.  I will have to insert `registerParent(turretPtr,soldierPtr);` too.    It is less maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

As you indicated yourself, there is a generic term "holder" covering tanks and turrets.
Model that in your classes.
Then you can maintain within soldier a reference to whatever it is in and let that handle the exit/enter of a soldier appropriately.
This way you only ever have to search through a very short list of soldiers in a tank and only in the one tank in which the soldier actually sits.

```
struct Soldier;

struct Holder
{
public:
    virtual void AddSoldier(Soldier* Entering)=0;
    virtual void ExitSoldier(Soldier* Exiting)=0;
}

struct Turret:
public holder
{
public:
    virtual void AddSoldier(Soldier* Entering)
    {   
        gunner=Entering;
        AttachedTo->AddSoldier(Entering);
    }
    virtual void ExitSoldier(Soldier* Exiting)
    /* this only covers the complete way of exiting,
       add another method for moving only into the tank */
    {    if(gunner=Exiting)
         {
             gunner=nullptr;
         }
         if(AttachedTo)
         {
             AttachedTo->ExitSoldier(Exiting);
         }
    }
    Soldier* gunner=nullptr;
    Tank*    AttachedTo;
};
struct Tank
: public holder
{
    virtual void AddSoldier(Soldier* Entering)
    {
        /* push Entering,
           if not in already */
    }

    virtual void MoveSoldierToTurretIfFree(Soldier* NewGunner)
    {/* you know .. */}

    virtual void ExitSoldier(Soldier* Exiting)
    {    
          AttachedTurret->ExitSoldier(Exiting);
          /* find and remove Exiting,
            tolerating if already left */

    }
    std::vector<Soldier*> passenger;
    struct turret* AttachedTurret;
};

struct Soldier{
    private: int team=0;
             Holder* Within;
    public: void setTeam(int teamP){
        team=teamP;
        //should insert callback
    }
    void IsTraitor (void)
    {
        Within->ExitSolder(this);
        Within=nullptr;
    }
};
```

I was a bit generours with the `public`, surely some fine-tuning is possible and desirable there.
I wrote the method code directly into the class, you will have to move it to code files or at least separate implementations in order to get it compilable; otherwise the forward-declared Soldier class might not be sufficient.

Comment: What about "A `Soldier` can reside in 1 `Turret` and 1 `Tank` at the same time."?

Comment: A soldier is in a turret and the turret is attached to a tank. That is why exiting a turret has the turret call the tanks exit method.

Comment: Hmm, I answer your question (in the comment) as 1)yes 2)"No, it is not applicable with current design"  ....  Sorry if my answers are misleading. >.<, but thank, your answer is useful.

Comment: I found your multipart answer hard to parse. Feel free to invite me to a chat room. Maybe I can get the answer to help even more.

Comment: Why shouldn't we talk here? (I rarely use out-of-SO chat, so don't know a proper one.)

Comment: Use SO-chat then. You need to help me understand your problem. That is likely to get longer than is meant in comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200211/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-javalover).